# XSLT Transformations

Tags: xml, xslt, transformation

I have a XML file of:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Batch BatchID="896" BatchName="20120629.130504">
    <Document DocumentType="XML Question">
        <Fields>
            <Field FieldName="Doc_ID">1</Field>
            <Field FieldName="Vendor_Code">126400</Field>
            <Field FieldName="Property_Code">10519</Field>
            <Field FieldName="Invoice_Num">20509</Field>
        </Fields><Files />
    </Document>
</Batch>
```

and I want to convert it to look something like below using an XSLT file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<ABCRelease>
  <ABC>
    <Doc_Id>1345</Doc_Id>
    <Vendor_Code>134500</Vendor_Code>
    <Property_Code>105559</Property_Code>
    <Invoice_Num>2034539</Invoice_Num>
  </ABC>
</ABCRelease>
```

My first time playing with XML and I have spent many hours not getting to far today and done a lot of searching on the topic. Is anyone able to help me out and provide some sample code that would enable this?

My problem has been in extracting the FieldName value and inserting it in the <> eg from:

```
<Field FieldName="Doc_ID">1</Field>
```

to

```
<Doc_Id>1345</Doc_Id>
```

Really would appreaciate your help.

Steven

Comment: Be careful of creating elements based on an attribute value, if a `FieldName` attribute contains a value that cannot be used as an element name, such as a numeric value or a name with a space, a transformation will need to catch this. Provided you have complete control over the values used this shouldn't cause you a problem, but it's definitely something to be aware of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="Fields">
   <ABCRelease>
    <ABC>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </ABC>
   </ABCRelease>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Field">
  <xsl:element name="{@FieldName}">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<Batch BatchID="896" BatchName="20120629.130504">
    <Document DocumentType="XML Question">
        <Fields>
            <Field FieldName="Doc_ID">1</Field>
            <Field FieldName="Vendor_Code">126400</Field>
            <Field FieldName="Property_Code">10519</Field>
            <Field FieldName="Invoice_Num">20509</Field>
        </Fields>
        <Files />
    </Document>
</Batch>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
<ABCRelease>
   <ABC>
      <Doc_ID>1</Doc_ID>
      <Vendor_Code>126400</Vendor_Code>
      <Property_Code>10519</Property_Code>
      <Invoice_Num>20509</Invoice_Num>
   </ABC>
</ABCRelease>
```

**Explanation**:

Proper use of **[`<xsl:element>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#section-Creating-Elements-with-xsl%3aelement)** and [**AVT**](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#attribute-value-templates)s (Attribute Value Templates).

Comment: Thank you for your response! Works a treat

Comment: Works fine for the OP, but how would you adapt this to gracefully handle values of `FieldName` that are not valid element names, such as `"2" or "Doc Id"?

Comment: @Flynn1179 - I would ask the client what their requirement is.

Comment: @Flynn1179: A valid question -- it must be addressed to the OP.

Comment: Just a follow up on this question. This is working well but now I have a need to not have all the FieldName’s components used in the Result. This code takes all items and represents them in the new format. Is it possible to only take two of the components to be represented into the results?

Ie only output the Doc_ID and the Property_Code components. Can I directly call these instead of using the {@FieldName} and select=”.” Lines?

Comment: @user1490231, Please, ask a new question -- it's been more than six months since this question was answered.